# Pass date to sql query in matlab

Tags: sql, matlab, user-input

I can't figure out how to pass a date to my sql query in matlab. When I do it "statically" it workds perfectly well:

```
myquery1 = ['Select DeliveryMonth, Value '...
 ' FROM [mydatabase] '...
 ' where idcurve = 33 ' ...
 ' and deliverymonth <''20121130'' '...
  ' order by DeliveryMonth ']
```

But what I want is this:

```
breakdate = input('Enter a breakdate as 20121130: ', 's')

myquery1 = ['Select DeliveryMonth, Value '...
 ' FROM [mydatabase] '...
 ' where idcurve = 33 ' ...
 ' and deliverymonth <   ''breakdate'' '...
  ' order by DeliveryMonth ']
```

regards
A

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a single quote mark:

```
breakdate = '20121130'
myquery1 = ['Select DeliveryMonth, Value '...
 ' FROM [mydatabase] '...
 ' where idcurve = 33 ' ...
 ' and deliverymonth < '''breakdate''' '...
  ' order by DeliveryMonth ']
```

which returns:

```
myquery1 =

Select DeliveryMonth, Value  FROM [mydatabase]  where idcurve = 33  and deliverymonth < '20121130'  order by DeliveryMonth
```

Comment: checking myquery1 it just retursn ...deliverymonth < 'breakdate'... There must be some conversion problems somewhere.

Comment: Ok, so I solved this by using a great GUI from mathworks at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8313-uigetdate/content/uigetdate.m and then changing my code to myquery1 = ['Select DeliveryMonth, Value '...
 ' FROM [ENOI_INDICI].[dbo].[v_mdm_MCurves] '...
 ' where idcurve = 33 '...
 ' and deliverymonth <',' ''',datestr(breakdate,29),' '''...
 ' order by DeliveryMonth ']

Answer (score 0):

```
 ' and deliverymonth < '  + breakdate + ...
```

Comment: Sorry no doesn't work. ahve tried this: ' and deliverymonth <',' ''breakdate '' '... which doesn't give any errors but also does not return any data...